# Gradients are None while implementing GradCam

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to implement grad-cam for a tensorflow 2.0 model (created using the keras-api), but the gradients returned from the tape are always None.

I am following the example given on https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/.

My model is fairly simple, but I swapped it out for the builtin Xception model provided by tf.keras.applications in order to debug (no difference in behavior, so the problem must be with my code).

```py
    # model (not shown here) is Xception from tf.keras.applications
    cam_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        [model.inputs],
        [model.get_layer(conv_layer_name).output, model.output] # conv_layer_name = 'block14_sepconv2_act'
    )

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        conv_out, predictions = cam_model(image)
        class_out = tf.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)

    grads = tape.gradient(class_out, conv_out)

    if grads is None: # grads is None
        raise Exception("Grad cam has recorded no gradient")
```

This is simple enough, I fail to see why the gradients are None. I suspect the tape might not be recording, but given the colab in https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/grad_cam.ipynb nothing seems to be required.

There is a related question but the convolution layer was incorrect, whereas here it's indeed the correct layer.

**EDIT**

So the `argmax` was problematic in the case of Xception, but fixing this (using predictions directly for instance) does not work for my model. Here is the model definition code:

```
    backbone = VGG16(
        include_top=False,
        weights='imagenet',
        input_shape=(*size, 3),
        pooling='max'
    )

    backbone.trainable = False

    net = Sequential()

    for layer in backbone.layers:
        net.add(layer)

    net.add(Flatten())
    net.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    net.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    net.add(Dense(len(CLASSES), activation='softmax'))
```

This is in tensorflow 2.8.0, on GPU.

Comment: But is argmax differentiable?

Comment: You're right (it's not). Rookie mistake while adapting the example

Comment: Fixing this works for Xception, but not my model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @AloneTogether mentionned, the result of `argmax` is not differentiable, thus the None result after applying `tape.gradients(...)` is normal, since no gradient can be computed.

While the result of `argmax` cannot be differentiated, it can be used to select the correct activation in the following way:

```py
        class_pred = tf.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)
        class_out = predictions[:, class_pred]
```

This solves this problem (by using Xception).

The other problem, using my full model, was disconnected graph errors when trying to access the inner layer of VGG16. I was able to fix this in a somewhat unsatisfying way, by using the input of VGG16 as the first layer of a model and using the output of VGG16 as the next available layer (using the functional API):

```py
    x = vgg16.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    ...
    return Model(vgg16.input, x)
```

The graph of the network will be fully expanded, meaning you will not have a "vgg" block, but all the layers of VGG unrolled. I think it's possible to have a non-unrolled version but I was unable to achieve it. This answer hints as this being possible: [Heatmap on custom model with transfer learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66571767/heatmap-on-custom-model-with-transfer-learning)